# Movie where there's a cave with hundreds of human-headed spiders

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

In the story, there are several people (two or four) who enter a cave. In the cave, there is a spider the size of a chair, and the spider cut off the head of the person who was caught from his body.

Then the head of the severed person merged with the spider, so that the spider had a human head, and chased the person who entered the cave. The number of spiders with human heads was hundreds.

Then the person being chased ran until he came out of the cave, and closed the cave with a kind of spell of words. When the cave is closed, all the human-headed spiders are sucked into the cave and seem to disappear.

This film was screened around 2006 and below, and played on Asian themes. I don't know if it was made in China, Hong Kong, Taiwan, or elsewhere.

Comment: The trope is shown in little nicky

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is ***[Hiruko the Goblin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100991/)*** (1991).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiruko_the_Goblin):

> *Hiruko the Goblin* (*Yōkai Hantā: Hiruko* (妖怪ハンター ヒルコ, *Yōkai Hunter: Hiruko*)) is a 1991 Japanese horror film directed by Shinya Tsukamoto and starring Kenji Sawada. It is based on a [manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga) by Daijiro Morohoshi.

From IMDB:

> A school was built on one of the Gates of Hell, behind which hordes of demons await the moment they will be free to roam the Earth. **Hiruko is a goblin sent to Earth on a reconnaissance mission. He beheads students in order to assemble their heads on the demons' spider-like bodies.** Hieda, an archaeology professor, and Masao, a haunted student, investigate the gory deaths and eventually battle Hiruko.

And here's an excerpt from a review of the film.

> *Hiroku the Goblin* has always been a bit of the black sheep of early j-horror. The movie was made to attract more western people to Japanese horror movies. It was released in 1991 but ended up being a poor sell. J-horror was evolving in the early 90tees, and this was one of the casualties in that time. Shinya Tsukamoto was one of the biggest upcoming directors around that time. His sci-fi/horror movie *Tetsuo: The Iron Man* left most critics speechless. Tsukamoto had been looking at too many US horror films.
>
> <sub>[*Hiroku the Goblin* (*Yôkai Hantâ: Hiruko*) Review](http://www.slashingthrough.com/reviews.php?id=53)</sub>

Comment: Wow, that's really fast, thank you very much, that's right, that's the movie